# fb-contrib not showing up in the Eclipse plugin

Tags: findbugs

The [fb-contrib web page](http://fb-contrib.sourceforge.net) sounds easy: Just dump the fb-contrib.jar into the plugins folder of Eclipse, restart Eclipse, and that's it. The list of detectors in the Findbugs preferences dialog did not become longer after I did that.

The preferences dialog offers to add a plugin manually. Doing that adds the plugin to the list, but the list of detectors is still the same. I'm using fb-contrib 4.8.3, Eclipse 4.2, Findbugs 2.0.2.

Comment: I installed a fresh Eclipse 4.3 and repeated the same steps there. Works instantly. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked ONLY if the jar was named exactly "fb-contrib.jar" (without the version number).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse 4.4 with FindBugs 3.0.0 and fb-contrib-6.0.0.jar, I had to add the jar with the button "Add..." under Preferences -> Java -> FindBugs -> Plugins and misc. Settings.